# JCommander: Is it possible to use multiple Validators in @Parameter?

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I'm using [JCommander](http://jcommander.org/)

F.e. I have a Dir path parameter and File path parameter. I want to store them in `File outDir` and `File inFile` variables corresponding. I want to create 3 validators. `PathExists`, `FileReadable` and `IsDirectory`. For the 1st one I'll use `PathExists` && `IsDirectory` and for the 2nd one `PathExists` && `FileReadable`.
Unfortunately documentation does not describe such case.

Comment: i'd try `validateWith={PathExists.class, FileReadable.class}` just in case (like `names`, although it isn't plural).